# ng-model into ui-gmap-marker

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

I need help to use ng-model directive with ui-gmap-marker. My example app.js is:

```
// DevicesController
$scope.devices = {
   id: 1,
   center: { latitude: X, longitude Y },
   options: {
       show: true,
       name: 'device 1',
       radius: 100 
   }
   (...)
}
```

My index.html is:

```
  <ul ng-controller="DevicesController">
      <li ng-repeat="d in devices">
           <input type="checkbox" ng-model="d.options.show">
           <span>{{ d.options.name }}</span>
      </li>
  </ul>
  (...)

  <div id="map_canvas" ng-controller="DevicesController">
      <ui-gmap-marker 
          ng-repeat="d in devicesMarkers track by d.id" 
          idkey="d.id"
          coords="d.center"
          ng-model="d.options.show">
      </ui-gmap-marker>
 (...)
```

How can I use ng-model? Doesn't work because I'm using the same controller e two different places? I want that the user be able to click in input checkbox and the marker appear/disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest simply wrap both the div in same controller rather than providing a separate controller to them.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-controller="DevicesController">
  <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="d in devices">
           <input type="checkbox" ng-model="d.options.show">
           <span>{{ d.options.name }}</span>
      </li>
  </ul>
  (...)

  <div id="map_canvas">
      <ui-gmap-marker 
          ng-repeat="d in devicesMarkers track by d.id" 
          idkey="d.id"
          coords="d.center"
          ng-model="d.options.show">
      </ui-gmap-marker>
 </div>
 (...)

</div>
```

Else maintain the data in share able service that will provide the data to both controller and will make sure, data should be updated in both places.